# Counting the amout of true elements in a sql to ling table

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to see how many have paid in full, the paid in full is a bit, but Visual Studio  and Linq converts it to a  bool?

The code below wont work unless I cast it but how do I cast it? I have tried multiple ways.

```
int i = (from c in YSA.YSAs
                where c.YSA_PAID_FULL = true
                select c).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `==` not `=`

```
int i = (from c in YSA.YSAs
         where c.YSA_PAID_FULL == true
         select c).Count();
```

Comment: thank you the bottom simple code still needs a cast but the "==" works:)

Comment: @user1901799, it shouldn't but glad your problem is solved. Removed my other part from the answer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use `==` operator

```
where c.YSA_PAID_FULL == true
```

Like;

```
int i = (from c in YSA.YSAs
                where c.YSA_PAID_FULL == true
                select c).Count();
```